# highchart scatter with 24 hours time on y axis and the day of the transaction on x axis

Tags: jquery, highcharts, scatter

I have some transaction data, and i want to create graphical chart report with y axis which have 24 hours (what time did the transaction occured) and x axis which explain what day did the transaction occured.

I use jquery highchart scatter, and i want something like this
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltPye.jpg). This is result when I use a little example data.

But when I insert too many data, it become weird like this
[weird result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xIsGn.jpg).

This is my code:

```
Highcharts.chart('graph', {
chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    zoomType: 'xy'
},
title: {
    text: 'Transaction Hour'
},
subtitle: {
    text: '1 year'
},
xAxis: {
categories: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'],
    title: {
        enabled: true,
        text: 'Days'
    },
    startOnTick: true,
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: true
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
    enabled: true,
    text: 'Time'
},
type: 'datetime',
dateTimeLabelFormats: { //force all formats to be hour:minute:second
        second: '%H:%M:%S',
        minute: '%H:%M:%S',
        hour: '%H:%M:%S',
        day: '%H:%M:%S',
        week: '%H:%M:%S',
        month: '%H:%M:%S',
        year: '%H:%M:%S'
}
},
legend: {
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: 100,
    y: 70,
    floating: true,
    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF',
    borderWidth: 1
},
plotOptions: {
    scatter: {
        marker: {
            radius: 4,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    enabled: true,
                    lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                }
            }
        },
        states: {
            hover: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br>',
            pointFormat: '{point.x}, {point.y}'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'A',
    color: 'rgba(153, 255, 102, .5)',
    data: [[Friday,1580455597000]]// unix timestamp

}, {name: 'B',
    color: 'rgba(223, 83, 83, .5)',
    data: [[Thursday,1580372483000],[Thursday,1580359660000]]// unix timestamp

}, {
    name: 'C',
    color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
    data: [[Friday,1580439732000]]// unix timestamp
}]
});
```

Can you help me?Thank you before.

Best Regards,

Eka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that using this structure of data totally disturbs your config. You have set the `yAxis.type` to the 'datatime' and you want to have the range 24 hours range, but one of your data points is `Fri Jan 31 2020 07:26:37` and the second one is `Thu Jan 30 2020 08:21:23` what gives you almost 23 hours range between only two points. Adding the third point makes that your yAxis will increase to another time range.

Try to use this config instead: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5e6sfcuq/

I used the `labels.formatter` callback to get the wanted format on axes. And the `min` and `max` features on the yAxis to keep the constant range.

And here is my proposal of data structure:

```
data: [
  [1580455597000,new Date(1580455597000).getHours()]
] // unix timestamp
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.tickInterval

If something is unclear - feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Let me try your solution then i will tell the result to you later.

Comment: Is it possible if I use data like this?How to set x axis configuration if i want to show transaction in 1 year.                                                          
[Friday,new Date(1580455597000).getHours()],                                       
[Thursday,new Date(1580372483000).getHours()],                                  
[Thursday,new Date(1580359660000).getHours()],                                       
[Friday,new Date(1580439732000).getHours()]

Comment: @Eka Notice that using this format of data will keep all your data points in one column, because their x value is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hxwy7g4r/

Comment: How to getHours and getMinutes together if the time is 14:37:28? If I want to get result 14,37

Comment: @Eka please take a look at general JavaScript documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMinutes

Comment: That is exactly what i want. Thank you so much for your help.